# How to securely setExternalUserId() in OneSignal?

Tags: security, push-notification, onesignal, web-push

I'm setting up OneSignal on my website.

As far as I can see, there are 2 ways I can associate a push subscription with my user ID:

- I can call `OneSignal.getUserId()`, which returns a UUID, and make an authenticated call to my web server to associate this UUID with my logged in user **on my server**
- I can call `setExternalUserId()` to send the logged in user ID and associate it with the subscription **on OneSignal servers**

The first option is perfectly secure, as one could only hijack my client-side code to send an invalid subscription ID (or another valid subscription ID *they* have created), which is not a big deal.

The second option though, feels totally unsecure: anyone could hijack the client-side code to send any valid user ID and associate it with its subscription, and therefore receive notifications on behalf of another user.

**Is there a way to securely use `setExternalUserId()` while preventing a user from associating their subscription with another user?**

The only secure scenario I can think of is if my users had UUIDs as well, instead of sequential IDs, and these UUIDs were kept secret (i.e. never exposed publicly on the website).

Any other scenario I can think of sounds plain insecure.

**Did I miss something?**

Comment: I think that your reasoning is correct, and that the only option of securing `setExternalUserId()` is to use long random tokens. However I think that a better alternative would be to use cryptographic signatures for setting the user IDs: I am the founder of Pushpad and indeed for our service we always require a signature for settings the user ID. IMHO our approach is secure by default, you can use the actual user IDs (instead of long random tokens) and you can easily invalidate all the signatures by revoking / replacing 1 master key (instead of millions of user IDs).

Comment: It is true, and pushpad does it very well. Still, If you have only 40 users you'll have to pay 10$/month.... so I think Onesignal is worth the risk in this case if you have less than 5000 users.